# Why can I no longer do live edits in chrome developer tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, developer-tools

I am creating a website and I used to make changes in the .js files in the Sources tab. These changes were directly reflected in the page. However, for some reason this does not work anymore. Note I am not willing to save these changes. It is just to do some quick tweaks and see the results directly. I tried it on another PC as well and also via Edge developer tools. Even older version of my website were it worked earlier.

Any suggestion, I am completely lost on what has caused this??